# i cant boot ubuntu after trying to install burg

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, burg

So I tried to install Burg through super boot manager and so I clicked remove grub and then install burg. So I did that and it said that it was successful so I rebooted to see what it looked like and if it worked and windows booted automatically without showing any sort of boot menu and I tried boot repair and lots of things on the Internet but nothing worked. Also I can boot into windows 10 still and also use my installation Disk to boot a live session.
If you need more information about my problem then just ask, I just wanted to get my question out here so i can get this fixed. Or is there maybe a way to boot ubuntu without using grub and or burg?

Answer (score 1):

you could try this boot from live session, and then write this in the tty:

```
 grub-install
 update-grub
 update-grub2
 grub-mkrescue
```

and the it sould work fine this way.

Comment: i was able to do update-grub and update-grub2 but when i type grub-mkrescue this is what it says > 
root@ubuntu:/# grub-install Installing for x86_64-efi platform. grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.